# Spring mechanism similar to OSGI/ Eclipse extension point

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, plugins, osgi

We wrote a framework which uses spring under the hood. This framework is used by two applications. It is possible to configure a production server with running application1 OR application2 OR application1 and application2.

Now I am looking for a spring mechanism which works similar to OSGI Extension-point idea, so that each application can "contribute" to framework without a configuration file where all applications need to be listed.

Complete project-structure (simplified ;-)):

Framework: A, IPlugin, A.xml

Application 1: B extends IPlugin, b.xml

Application 2: C extends IPlugin, c.xml

Explenation:
"A" uses a list of IPllugin which will be called if a specific task has to be achieved.

I only found the spring way of declaring A as prototyp and setting "B" and "C" as attributes. Therefore I have to list both explicitly in A.xml. But I want to configure contributions in b.xml and c.xml.

Questions:

- Is there a possibility in spring to be modified if an instance of a special kind of bean is created?
- Is there something similar to OSGI/Eclipse extension-point in spring out of the box?
- Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to be able to add/remove any of your applications from/to your framework in run-time?

Comment: I agree dm might be your best bet, otherwise I'd consider a simple plugin mechanism; the registration handler could be injected, too.

Comment: Adding and removing does not need to happen during runtime. @DaveNewton I thought about this approach but was not able to develop a solution. Could you provide some hints or do you have an example?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to reasonably answer this question since we don't know how your framework works or how the applications can contribute to it.  If, for example, it is a simple Observer/Observable type of scenario then it should be easily accomplished, with or without Spring.  Any potential solutions will be based on assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create a "registry" in the framework project which will be created in spring with scope "singleton". So each plugin can contribute to this registry because it is available to all plugins during runtime of the application server. Since each plugin should be created new I used the help of a factory which creates new plugin-instances from spring-context.

More details can be found in a small article I wrote and which can be [downloaded](http://www.m-krausse.de/articles/minimalOsgiWithSpring/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring Dynamic Modules](http://www.springsource.org/osgi).  The first line of the introduction says it all:

> The Spring Dynamic Modules for OSGi(tm) Service Platforms project makes it easy to build Spring applications that run in an OSGi framework

Comment: Does it mean that I need a runtime which supports OSGI? Since our application runs in an old tomcat this might not work for us. :-( But I am going to have a look at the framework, maybe it gives me some ideas

Comment: The OP is looking for OSGi like functionality in Spring WITHOUT OSGi.  Spring DM works in an OSGi container.

Comment: And at what point is that stated?  Just because the asker wants something like OSGI, it doesn't mean that they are not willing to use OSGI.  The second question at the end of the post says it all.  Something similar to OSGI that Spring supports, what is more like OSGI than OSGI?

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough but I wanted something like a basic OSGI without dynamic adding/ removing plugins. Because OSGI would be a little bit overkill for my problem. At the moment I have an idea how to solve the problem and will post it as soon as it is working. :-)

Comment: @nicholas - The second question is "Is there something similar to OSGI/Eclipse extension-point in spring out of the box?"  That is very different from something that Spring supports.  DM is an add on to OSGi, not something like OSGi inside of Spring.  The question implies getting OSGi like features using Spring only, not integrating Spring with OSGi, which is what DM does.

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested using OSGi with Spring-DM or Blueprint. If you decide that's what you want to do -- and I'm not sure about that myself because I didn't entirely understand the problem description -- then you should be able to embed an OSGi framework into your existing application (yes, even inside Tomcat...).

I wrote a [blog post](http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html) on how to embed OSGi that might help you to get started. But check out first whether OSGi with Spring-DM is really what you want, and do ask follow up questions if you need help making that decision.